# Different ways to make "Create or replace" function in PLpgSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am very new to database systems, SQL,PLpgsql,postgresql etc. I am learning about create and replace, and i can only think of one way to make the create and replace function for example:

```
RETURNS trigger AS $$
--Begins function
BEGIN

    perform phone, email from contact ;

if (new.phone) is null  OR (new.email) is null then RAISE EXCEPTION 'Bitte geben Sie mindestens eine der folgenden Informationen an: 1. Handy-Nummer 2. E-Mail Adresse' ;
END IF; 
Return new;
END;
$$
```

How can I write this same function differently something that is much shorter, is that possible, if possible can someone show me how it could be don, the possible ways to rewrite this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PERFORM`, which actually executes a sequential scan of the complete table and then discards the result, is totally unnecessary, and you should remove it.

`NEW` is automatically populated in `FOR EACH ROW` triggers on `INSERT OR UPDATE`, so the second line alone is good enough. Use a `BEFORE` trigger for performance.